# How can I use Client ID within a server control?

Tags: asp.net

I was able to do the following in a repeater and it works just fine:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtOtherPartyName" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' runat="server" />
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqLoss" ControlToValidate="txtOtherPartyName"
    data-valmsg-for='<%# Container.FindControl("txtOtherPartyName").ClientID%>' 
    Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Name of party involved is required." runat="server" />
```

The data-valmsg-for attribute in the required validator rendered the server control id just fine.  How can I do the same for a control that sits on a page and is not within a repeater?  I tried similar things without any luck.

**Update**

So here's what I'm looking to do exactly:

```
<asp:Textbox id="txtTest" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="reqTest" data-valmsg-for=**[i want the html rendered id of "txtTest" here]** runat="server" />
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the client id of a control that is not in the repeater OR are you trying to bind the client id of one of the repeater's controls to another control outside of the repeater?

Comment: I'm trying to get the client id of a control that is not in a repeater.  I was just using the repeater as an example that I could obtain the client id from within one, which gives me hope that I can do the same for a server control that is not inside a repeater.

Comment: Ah ok.  Should just be <%= ControlName.ClientID %>  Make sure you give the control an ID when you declare it in the markup.

Comment: That will render plain text, e.g - data-valmsg-for=<%= ControlName.ClientID %>

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding your intention.  I thought you wanted to assign the Client Id as a string value of some control to an attribute of another control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind that custom attribute to the control's client id in the code behind.

```
butthead.Attributes.Add("data-custom-prop", beavis.ClientID);
```

Comment: No problem.  It does however strike my curiosity as to why this can't be declared in the markup.  If someone knows the answer to that then that would be icing on the cake!

Answer (score 0):

In the `Repeater` you used databinding syntax (`<%# ... %>`), but that doesn't apply in this case. You *should* be able to set the attribute like this:

```
data-valmsg-for='<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>'
```

Why are you adding custom attributes to the validators in the first place though, if you don't mind me asking? What purpose does it serve that can't be achieved through other means?

**EDIT**

Have you considered building your list of control IDs in code-behind beforehand, and storing it somewhere? Could something like this be a starting point?:

```
var controlList = Page.Validators.OfType<BaseValidator>()
    .Select(v => Page.FindControl(v.ControlToValidate).ClientID).ToList();
```

**EDIT**

Expanding on that idea, you can serialize the list to JSON using the `JavaScriptSerializer` (`System.Web.Script.Serialization`):

```
//initialize the javascript serializer
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

//retrieve all of the validators on the page and store the client ids in a list
var controlList = Page.Validators.OfType<BaseValidator>()
    .Select(v => Page.FindControl(v.ControlToValidate).ClientID).ToList();

//serialize the control id list and register the script block on the page
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "data", string.Format("var data = {0}", serializer.Serialize(controlList)), true);
```

Depending on how complex the form is, you may need to create a recursive function to find all of the controls, but hopefully this demonstrates the concept.

Comment: Using that method will render the tag as plain text.  It's a long story but the reason I'm doing this is because I am presenting a very customized validation UI that includes a summary with links that take the user to the control, along with tooltips that display the error message. I use the data-valmsg-for attributes to scan over the errors and build my custom display.

Comment: How is it rendered in the code example above? Shouldn't that output the `ClientID` in the `data-valmsg-for` attribute too?

Comment: It just renders as plain text: <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_reqLoss" data-valmsg-for="<%= drplstLoss.ClientID %>" style="color:Red;display:none;">Loss is required.</span>

Comment: Oh! I see what you mean. Try using *single quotes* instead: `data-valmsg-for='<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>'`

Comment: Unfortunately that will render plain text as well :(

Comment: I posted another solution you might want to check out, but using your current approach I would suggest creating your own validator control (custom server control) that supports that attribute.